# django - make a single object in a list editable

Tags: django, forms, view, edit

I have a site to manage different Groups. So far I can add groups and delete them. My problem is that I don't know how I can make them editable.

[image: How the page looks like]

What I want: If you click on the edit button the line clicked should change to an editable field. Next to edit should stand save and cancel.

How the model looks like:

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_altered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.value)
```

How the form looks like:

```
class UserGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Init the form."""
        super(UserGroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = UserGroup
        fields = '__all__'
```

Accessing form in the template:

```
{% for group in groups %}
<p>{{ group.value }}    ({{ group.description }})   <a href="/group/edit/{{ group.id }}/">edit</a> <a href="/group/delete/{{ group.id }}/">delete</a></p>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Generic editing views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/) are probably what you are looking for. Documentation should be really self explanatory as it's fairly short and basic.

Comment: The documentation is short and basic, that's the problem. I don't see how I can realize in-line edit with this documentation. As I understand it they create a completely new page just for editing a single line. I want to click on edit button and stay on the same page. Only difference should be that I can change the text and then click save.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your OP slightly and fear I can't really help you since I've never done anything like that yet. However what you'll want to look out for are [Editing Mixins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/).